# Returning rows with where and or clause not returning correct values

Tags: sql

I have the following query, which is supposed to return [issued date] and [Date Made] according to the same where and or criteria.

In other words if I have a date of 04/01/2020 for [Date Made] and a date of 04/01/2020 for [Issued Date], the data returned should be 04/01/2020 for all records. Currently the [Date Made] is correct, but the [Date Issued] is returning additional dates.

```
DECLARE 
    @Compound VARCHAR(30) = 'All',
    @SkidID VARCHAR(100) = 'All'

DECLARE @SkidCount INT;
    
SELECT 
    Reprint AS 'Reprint',
    comp.ID,
    SkidID AS 'Skid ID',
    PartNumber AS 'Compound',
    Quantity AS 'Qty',
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DateMade, 101) AS 'Date Made',
    WorkOrderNumber AS 'E1 Work Order Number',
    WorkOrderDesc AS 'Work Order Desc',
    IssuedDate AS 'Issued Date',
    (SELECT TOP 1 cn.Name
     FROM dbo.ClockNum cn
     WHERE cn.ClockNum = comp.PrintedByClockNumber) AS 'PrintedBy',
    PrintedDateTime AS 'DateTimePrinted',
    (SELECT TOP 1 cn.Name
     FROM dbo.ClockNum cn
     WHERE cn.ClockNum = comp.IssuedByClockNumber) AS 'IssuedBy',
    CurrentLocation AS 'Current Location',
    PreviousLocation AS 'Previous Location'
FROM 
    dbo.Components comp WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    DateMade >= '2021-01-04 00:00:00.000'
    AND DateMade <= '2021-01-04 23:59:59.000'
    OR comp.IssuedDate >= '2021-01-04 00:00:00.000'
    AND comp.IssuedDate <= '2021-01-04 23:59:59.000'
    AND (PartNumber = 'All' OR @Compound = 'All')
    AND (SkidID LIKE '%' + @SkidID + '%' OR @SkidID = 'All')
    AND (ReversedBy IS NULL AND ReversalDate IS NULL)
    AND (CurrentLocation = 'Jackson')
ORDER BY 
    [Date Made] DESC;
```

I am thinking it is the way I have implemented the or clause ? (See data below)

[image]

Comment: You have an "or" between the check for DateMade and IssuedDate, meaning only one of those need to be true for it to be returned.  If both DateMade and IssuedDate need to be on Jan 4, 2021, then you need to change that OR to an AND.

Comment: If I change the or to and it returns no records. `  (    DateMade >= '2021-01-04 00:00:00.000'
                  AND DateMade <= '2021-01-04 23:59:59.000' 
              
             )
              
     and 
     ( comp.IssuedDate >= '2021-01-04 00:00:00.000'
                     AND comp.IssuedDate <= '2021-01-04 23:59:59.000' )`

Comment: Parentheses are critical when mixing OR and AND operators. `(this or this) and this` is not the same as `this or (this and this)`. `this or this and this` will be interpreted as the first example. You seem to be aware of this with the OR phrases within the later AND's. Suggest you need to clarify logic of the first AND and OR with parentheses.

Comment: If you get no data, then that tells me that you have no data where both DateMade and IssuedDate are Jan 4, 2021 AND ReveredBy is NULL AND ReversalDate is NULL AND CurrentLocation = 'Jackson'.  What specifically are the full conditions of the data you are trying to get?

Comment: I am with Russ here and think you only want `AND` and no `OR`. Moreover, you may have made a mistake here: `AND (PartNumber = 'All' OR @Compound = 'All')`. Maybe, but I am just guessing, you want `AND (PartNumber = @Compound OR @Compound = 'All')` instead.

Comment: @AaronBertrand says [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation sections for logical operators and their priorities. You also can use `between`.